# Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for extension 'springBoot' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have `build.gradle` like this and it works :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.8' apply false
    ...
}
...
    springBoot {
        mainClassName = 'com.mir3.service.contactfileparser.Main'
    }
```

but if I upgrade spring boot version to 2.6.2 it fails with error:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2' apply false
    ...
}
...
    springBoot {
        mainClassName = 'com.mir3.service.contactfileparser.Main'
    }
```

Error text is:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myProject'.
> Could not set unknown property 'mainClassName' for extension 'springBoot' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension.
```

How can I fix it ? What is the proper way to migrate from 2.5.8 to 2.6.2 ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use:

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.mir3.service.contactfileparser.Main'
}
```

`SpringBootExtension` has:

```java
/**
 * Returns the fully-qualified name of the application's main class.
 * @return the fully-qualified name of the application's main class
 * @since 2.4.0
 */
public Property<String> getMainClass() {
    return this.mainClass;
}
```

`mainClassName` was deprecated in favour of `mainClass` in 2.4.0 and was scheduled for removal in 2.6.0. It was removed with this commit: [Remove deprecated code flagged for removal](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/dc5acb00191c2eac09907c39e4d890343bf9848d#diff-ef03c7708a81d6f41f69961e5c539e8156554321c5c5da8058a8de970a102694)

Comment: great answer. just thought i'd vent - spring engineering sucks. changing property names to make them shorter is about the dumbest thing you can do.